# A person on a concrete slab on a frozen lake starts walking $ 2 m/s$ with respect to ground, what is the speed of the concrete slab w.r.t. ground?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, momentum

Full question:
[image: Full question]

My attempt:

Let the M be the mass of the person. Let x be the length of the slab.

The original center of mass is $\frac{5M\frac{x}{2}}{M + 5M}$.

Let's say the person walks a length of 2t. Let L be the amount the slab has moved relative to the ice after t seconds of the person walking. Then the new center of mass is $\frac{M(2t - L) + 5M(\frac{x}{2} - L)}{5M + M}$ Since there are no external forces, the center of masses should be the same. Therefore,

$5M\frac{x}{2} = M(2t - L) + 5M(\frac{x}{2} - L)$ Cancel out the M and let $x = 2$ since $x$ is constant anyway, so

$5 = 2t - L + 5(1-L)$

$5 = 2t - L + 5 - 5L$

$6L = 2t$

$L = \frac{2}{6}t$

In other words, $L$ is increasing at a rate of $\frac{2}{6} m/s$, so center of mass of the concrete slab is moving at $\frac{2}{6} m/s$.

However, the answer to this problem is $.400 m/s$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making it more complicated than it needs to be.  If your mass is $M$, your momentum is $2M$, so the momentum of the slab is $-2M$ and the velocity is $\frac {-2M}{5M}=-0.4$.  You don't know where the CM is because you don't know where the person is.  If the person starts in the center, the CM is at $\frac x2$